# wget cant find .listing?

Tags: linux, debian, wget

I want do download a whole directory from a FileZilla FTP server.
I use
`wget -r --user=XXXX --password='XXXX' ftp://XXXXXX.org:XX/Fertig/XXXXXX/`
the error says:

```
--2018-12-16 21:19:55--  ftp://XXX.org:XX/XXX/
           => »XXXXX.org:XXXX/XXX/.listing«
Auflösen des Hostnamens »XXXX.org (XXXX.org)« … XXXXXXXXX
Verbindungsaufbau zu XXX.org (XXX.org)|XXXXX|:XXX … verbunden.
Anmelden als XXX … Angemeldet!
==> SYST ... fertig.    ==> PWD ... fertig.
==> TYPE I ... fertig.  ==> CWD (1) /XXX ... fertig.
==> PASV ... fertig.    ==> LIST ... fertig.
XXXX.org:XXX/XXX: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefundenXXXX.org:XX/XXXX/.listing: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

when i want to download a single file, it works, but only a recursive directory fails...

Answer (score 0):

chmod 777 /media/usbdisk... now it works.

acess were denided.